# Python language construction when filtering the array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I can see many questions in SO about how to filter an array (usually using pandas or numpy). The examples are very simple:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] })
a = df[df.val > 3]
```

Intuitively I understand the `df[df.val > 3]` statement. But it confuses me from the syntax point of view. In other languages, I would expect a lambda function instead of `df.val > 3`.

The question is: Why this style is possible and what is going on underhood?

**Update 1:**

To be more clear about the confusing part: In other languages I saw the next syntax:

```
df.filter(row => row.val > 3)
```

I understand here what is going on under the hood: For every iteration, the lambda function is called with the `row` as an argument and returns a boolean value. But here `df.val > 3` doesn't make sense to me because `df.val` looks like a `column`.

Moreover, I can write `df[df > 3]` and it will be compiled and executed successfully. And it makes me crazy because I don't understand how a DataFrame object can be compared to a number.

Comment: Your code is wrong, need boolean indexing - `df[df.val > 3]`

Comment: Thank you. Fixed. But the question is the same.

Comment: You can index a numpy array with an array of booleans. That’s what the inequality creates.

Comment: this is called Boolean Indexing, see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: The common vectorized libraries in C++: `armadillo, Eigen, Valarray, opencv`, all use Boolean Indexing(NOT EXACTLY SIMILAR TO THIS); Julia, Matlab, R, uses boolean Indexing. So when you say *other languages expect lambda function* could you be more specific? If at all you transitioned from any of those languages while using vectorization, then you definitely understand what `A[A>2]` means. I am not sure of the good old languages Fortran, and the rest..

Comment: Have you looked at what `df.val` is? it is a column. Have you looked at what `df.val > 3` is? do you understand vectorization? Have you read the numpy documentation?

Comment: can also say that it is better to use: df[df['val'] > 3]. It is recommended, because a predefined variables with the same name may come across and you will not get what you want.

Comment: `obj[index] = value`  is the basic Python syntax part.  That's converted to `obj.__setitem__(index, value)` call, where `__setitem__` is a method defined for that class of objects.  In your case `obj` is of class `pandas.DataFrame`, which makes heavy use of `numpy` arrays.  `df.val>3` is a boolean Series (`df.val` is a pandas defined way of selecting a column, e.g. `df['val']`).   So the fact that it can set many values in `df` has nothing to do with a special Python syntax; it's a matter of how pandas defines its `__setitem__` method.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and dataframe from it:

```
In [104]: arr = np.arange(1,8); df = pd.DataFrame({'val':arr})

In [105]: arr
Out[105]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

In [106]: df
Out[106]: 
   val
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
```

`numpy` arrays have methods and operators that operate on the whole array.  For example you can multiply the array by a scalar, or add a scalar to all elements.  Or in this case compare each element to a scalar.  That's all implemented by the class (`numpy.ndarray`), not by Python syntax.

```
In [107]: arr>3
Out[107]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Similarly `pandas` implements these methods (or uses `numpy` methods on the underlying arrays).  Selecting a column of a frame, with `df['val'] or:

```
In [108]: df.val
Out[108]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
Name: val, dtype: int32
```

This is a pandas Series (slight difference in display).

It can be compared to a scalar - as with the array:

```
In [110]: df.val>3
Out[110]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: val, dtype: bool
```

And the boolean array can be used to index the frame:

```
In [111]: df[arr>3]
Out[111]: 
   val
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
```

The boolean Series also works:

```
In [112]: df[df.val>3]
Out[112]: 
   val
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
```

Boolean array indexing works the same way:

```
In [113]: arr[arr>3]
Out[113]: array([4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Here I use the indexing to fetch values; setting values is analogous.